# How to install Windows 7 from network?

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, boot

I want to install windows 7 on 10 pc  from  one shared source via same network and use the following:

1. windows PE bootable disk .
2. the source computer with windows 7 setup files in the share folder .
3. 10 target computer with lan device which support PXE .

On the computer that I want to install windows 7 on, boot it from windows PE bootable disk.
Follow any prompts and wait. After the while, the computer boot to a CMD window.
In the Cmd window, typed :

```
net use * \\{share source ip}\{share name }
```

and saw [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/379605) error.

But in windows 7 installed on it , I tryed this and saw :

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/379607

What should I do for solving this problem?

Answer (score 0):

What are you using as your deployment server? Have you installed WDS on the server first of all. If not, you won't get PXE to work. I would suggest also having a look at MDT :)